# How to open a webpage in Chrome from PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I am creating a large PowerShell script to change a bunch of system preferences and personalization options, as I am using a computer cluster where everything is wiped upon restart and I simply cannot be productive with the default settings.

More specifically, I would like to also enable "Ask where to save Downloads" in Chrome and change the default search engine from Google to Bing. I know of no way to do this from a script, and I don't think it's as simple as copying a file over that will change those settings, so I thought I could at least have my script open the settings window so I can do that more easily.

I can't figure out how to get PowerShell to open Chrome to a specific webpage. For example, the following does not work:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList 'chrome://settings/?search=ask+where'
```

I can open Chrome itself from PowerShell but not to anything but this page. I have tried moving the quotes around behind and after the Argument List, enclosing everything in quotes, and every other possible combination of quotes, etc.

I have spent an hour looking for solutions online. Every one of them entails either:

1. PowerShell opening the webpage, but using the default browser. (Chrome is not the default browser, and I am opening Chrome specific links anyways so that would not work in the default browser).
2. Opening Chrome with arguments that change how Chrome opens - i.e. "--incognito" for opening in Incognito.

I have found nothing that will let me open a webpage in Chrome. Is this even possible?

I realize now that the problem is the URL I am attempting to open, rather than the code which is fine.

However, I cannot do anything in the suggested answer. I can't make any changes at all to the filesystem, because everything is wiped upon logout. Hence the ps1 script to setup the environment. It needs to be quick so I can't copy over an entire GoogleChromePortable directory.

Comment: (1) One of the answers to the duplicate question suggests using AutoHotkey.  Have you investigated that?   (2) Have you tried running filemon and regmon while doing the changes manually?